# How to scroll element into view using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> i am new to programming and i want to implement a dropdown menu for which the user can navigate dropdown items using up and down arrow keys and enter key is used to select the dropdown item.
>
> Also i want the dropdown item highlighted to be visible to the user in the window without using dropdown menu scroll bar.
>
> To achieve that i implemented code below,
> It works fine. but while pressing up arrow key the highlighted dropdown menu is not in window view meaning it is not scrolling to view.

```
class Dropdownwithinput extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.list_item_ref = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            input_val: '',
            dropdown_values: [],
            item_selection: 0,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const values = [
            {
                id:1,
                name: somename,
            },

            {
                id: 2,
                name: fname,
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: lname,
            }
        ],
        this.setState({dropdown_values: values});
    }

    handle_key_down = (event) => {
        if (this.state.dropdown_values > 0) {
            if (event.keyCode === 38 && this.state.item_selection 
            > 0) {
                this.setState({item_selection: 
                (this.state.item_selection - 1) % 
                this.state.dropdown_values.length});
                let child_array = 
                Array.from(this.list_item_ref.current.children);
                const element_found = child_array.find(e =>
                    e.classList.contains("test") && 
                    e.classList.contains("highlight")
                );
                element_found && element_found.scrollIntoView();
             } else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
                 this.setState({item_selection: 
                 (this.state.dropdown_values_selection + 1) % 
                 this.state.dropdown_values.length});
                 let child_array = 
                 Array.from(this.list_item_ref.current.children);
                 const element_found = child_array.find(e =>
                     e.classList.contains("test") && 
                     e.classList.contains("highlight")
                 );
                 element_found && element_found.scrollIntoView();
             }

             if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 const selected_item = 
                 this.state.dropdown_values[this.state.user_selection];
                 const text = this.replace(this.state.input_val, 
                 selected_item);
                 this.setState({
                    input_val: text,
                    dropdown_values: [],
                 });
             }
        }

        replace = (input_val, selected_item) => {
            //some function to replace value in input field with the 
           //selected dropdown item
        }

        render = () => {
            return (
                <input 
                    onChange={this.handle_input_change}
                    onKeyDown={this.handle_key_down}/>
                <div ref={this.list_item_ref}>
                    {this.state.dropdown_values.map((item, index) => (
                        <div key={index} className={"test" + (index === 
                        this.state.item_selection ? ' highlight' 
                        : '')}>
                            {item.name}
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            )
        };
    }
}
```

I think the problem lies in the handle_key_down method itself. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: There are many improvements in code before it upto the point that we could start debugging like render method is inside handle_key_down function, React.PureComponent instead of React,Component. Can you bring the code upto the point where we can look at actual problem.

Comment: thanks. i think its inside this condition if (event.keyCode === 38 && this.state.item_selection > 0) in handle_key_down method that's not working correct. meaning it is not showing the element in view.

Comment: element_found variable is always containing element that is previously highlighted meaning if currently highlighted element is "fname"....element_found contains somename.